# Cannot parse/webscrape Canadian Tire website product data using BeautifulSoup or Selenium, outside DOM

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Good Day All,

Trying to parse various websites for product name and price and running into problems. I can parse websites like Toys R Us using:

```
header = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36'}
html_parser = 'html5lib'

def check_price_tru_d():
    html_tru_d = requests.get(
        'https://www.toysrus.ca/en/toysrus/Deals?pmax=100.00&pmin=20.00&prefn1=bvAverageRating&prefv1=4&srule=best-selling&start=0&sz=24#3',
        headers=header)
    bsobj_tru_d2 = soup(html_tru_d.text,html_parser)
    bsobj_tru_d = soup(bsobj_tru_d2.prettify(),html_parser)
    Product_Name = []
    Product_Current_Price = []
    Product_Regular_Price = []


    Product_Name_Index = bsobj_tru_d.find_all('a', {'class': 'b-product_tile-title_link js-pdp-link'})
    for anchor in Product_Name_Index:
        Product_Name.append(anchor.text)
    Product_Current_Price_Index = bsobj_tru_d.find_all('span', {'class': 'b-price-value js-sales-price-value'})
    for anchor in Product_Current_Price_Index:
        Product_Current_Price.append(anchor.text)
    Product_Regular_Price_Index = bsobj_tru_d.findAll('span', {'class': 'b-price-value js-list-price-value'})
    for anchor in Product_Regular_Price_Index:
        Product_Regular_Price.append(anchor.text)
    From_Which_Store = []

    count = 0
    num_Array = len(Product_Name)
    while count < num_Array:
        From_Which_Store.append(str("Toys R Us Deals"))
        count = count + 1

    data = np.transpose([Product_Name, Product_Current_Price, Product_Regular_Price, From_Which_Store])

    return(data)

labels = ['Product Name', 'Current Sale Price', 'Regular Price', 'Store']
data = np.concatenate((check_price_ct(), check_price_tru_d(),check_price_wsc()))
All_Scraped_Data = [dict(zip(labels, datum)) for datum in data]

print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(All_Scraped_Data))
```

I tried similar code for Canandian Tire. Ran into problems when it wouldn't return any results. Realized that the HTML code that BeautifulSoup was parsing was outside the 'DOM' (whatever that is) and wasn't showing up in the BSobj. Been trying to figure out how to get the product name and price for all the item on the page.

```
def check_price_ct():
    html_ct = requests.get('https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/search-results.html?index=product;lang=en;q=*;m_ct_sort=sort-rating-desc;x1=s.regional-promotion;q1=T;x2=HIDECROSSMERCH;q2=T;x3=s.save-percentage;q3=0.4-1;x4=s.store-list.instock;q4=true;x5=s.regional-price-range;q5=25-99.99%7C25-49.99%7C50-99.99%7C0-24.99;page=3', headers=header)
    bsobj_ct2 = soup(html_ct.content,html_parser)
    bsobj_ct = soup(bsobj_ct2.prettify(),html_parser)

    Product_Name = bsobj_ct.find_all('h3', {'class':'product-tile-srp__title grid--grid-view__item'})#<h3 class="product-tile-srp__title grid--grid-view__item">MAXIMUM 90-Tooth Ratcheting Wrench Set, 10-pc</h3>
    Product_Current_Price = bsobj_ct.find_all('price__now--value-srp')#<span class="price__total-value price__total--on-sale">$59.99</span>
    Product_Regular_Price = bsobj_ct.find_all('price__list--last-price')#<span class="product-tile__price-total-value-from product-tile__regular-price--on-sale">$149.99   </span>
    From_Which_Store = []

    count = 0
    num_Array = len(Product_Name)
    while count < num_Array:
        From_Which_Store.append(str("Canadian Tire"))
        count = count + 1

    data = np.transpose([Product_Name, Product_Current_Price, Product_Regular_Price, From_Which_Store])

    return(data)
```

Then through looking at forums and other examples of code moved from BeautifulSoup to Selenium, trying to query JS in order to get the product name:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/search-results.html?index=product;lang=en;q=*;m_ct_sort=sort-rating-desc;x1=s.regional-promotion;q1=T;x2=HIDECROSSMERCH;q2=T;x3=s.save-percentage;q3=0.4-1;x4=s.store-list.instock;q4=true;x5=s.regional-price-range;q5=25-99.99%7C25-49.99%7C50-99.99%7C0-24.99;page=3%27')

script = "return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('h3.product-tile-srp__title grid--grid-view__item'),':before').getPropertyValue('content')"
print(driver.execute_script(script).strip())
```

At any rate, I am stuck. Don't know how to get these product values out. Similar issues when I try Walmart and their 'data-automation=etc etc etc' class (https://www.walmart.ca/rollback?f=12+51&icid=homepage_HP_TopCategory_Rollbacks_WM&sort=Popular%3ADESC&price=20-100).

Hoping someone can shed some light on how to webscrape these websites correctly.

Imports

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import numpy as np
import smtplib
import html5lib
import time, os, sys, lxml
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
import httplib2
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

Comment: `https://api.canadiantire.ca/search/api/v0/product/en/?site=ct;store=0144;format=json;count=108;x1=s.regional-promotion;q1=T;x2=HIDECROSSMERCH;q2=T;x3=s.save-percentage;q3=0.4-1;x4=s.store-list.instock;q4=true;x5=s.regional-price-range;q5=25-99.99%7C25-49.99%7C50-99.99%7C0-24.99;m_ct_sort=sort-rating-desc;q=*;callback=callback`

Comment: You need to improve your locators i.e. xpath.

Comment: a side note regarding your code. parsing twice the page for no benefits: the parser has no need for prettified data, that function is for humans. and don't scrape parts separately: parse each container and get the data you _can_, but keep them together. with your method if one container lacks one of the data you expect, everything will be mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch the products data. You need to improve locator finding strategy , i.e. improve your xpath or css (whatever you prefer)

```
PATH = r"your chromedriver path"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/search-results.html? 
index=product;lang=en;q=*;m_ct_sort=sort-rating-desc;x1=s.regional- 
promotion;q1=T;x2=HIDECROSSMERCH;q2=T;x3=s.save-percentage;q3=0.4-1;x4=s.store- 
list.instock;q4=true;x5=s.regional-price-range;q5=25-99.99%7C25-49.99%7C50- 
99.99%7C0-24.99;page=3%27')
sleep(3)
driver.maximize_window()
all_products = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "*//div[@class='search-results- 
grid__content']")
print(all_products.text)

driver.quit()
```

**Output**:

```
New!
MAXIMUM 90-Tooth Ratcheting Wrench Set, 10-pc
SAVE UP TO 60% (UP TO $90)
From
$59.99
$149.99
Quick view for Availability
QUICK VIEW
MAXIMUM Hex Key Bit Socket Set, Metric, 9-pc
#058-9653-6
1/2 PRICE
$12.49
$24.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MAXIMUM Hex Impact Bit Socket Set, 14-pc
#058-0333-2
SAVE 60% ($48)
$31.99
$79.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Reload Universal Backup Camera
#035-0728-8
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $40)
$39.99
$79.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Mastercraft Screwdriver Bit Set, 37-pc
#054-0530-0
SAVE 60% ($30)
$19.99
$49.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
PADERNO Professional Uncoated Aluminum Round Cake Pan, 9-in
#142-4875-6
SAVE 40%
$17.99
$29.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
New!
Mastercraft Assorted Wire & Flap Brush Set, 10-pc
#054-2562-2
1/2 PRICE
$19.99
$39.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Mastercraft Drill, Drive & Fastening Bit Set, 350-pc
#054-0294-2
SAVE 60% ($80)
$49.99
$129.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Mega Bloks® First Builders Block Set Tube, 100-pc
#050-4692-8
SAVE 40%
$12.99
$21.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Peerless 2-Handle Lavatory Faucet, Chrome, 4-in
#063-3881-4
SAVE 40% ($38)
$56.99
$94.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Huntshield Base Layer Realtree XTRA Top
SAVE UP TO 40%
From
$29.99
$49.99
Quick view for Availability
QUICK VIEW
For Living Gold Stacked Gift Ball Ornament Set, Assorted, 40-pk
#151-4642-8
1/2 PRICE
$14.99
$29.99
In-store purchase only
QUICK VIEW
AutoTrends Luxury Linen & Faux Leather Seat Cushion
#032-0190-0
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $30)
$29.99
$59.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MotoMaster Heavy Duty Carpet Floor Mats
#031-7098-2
SAVE 40%
$29.99
$49.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Core Home Reusable Nylon Shopping Bags, 3-pk
#142-9242-2
SAVE 60%
$7.99
$19.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
For Living Stacked Unbreakable Ornament Gift Set, White, 40-pc
#151-7008-2
1/2 PRICE
$14.99
$29.99
In-store purchase only
QUICK VIEW
MotoMaster OEPLUS European 0W30 Premium Synthetic Engine Oil, 5-L
#028-7962-4
SAVE 45% ($27)
$27.99
$54.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MotoMaster OEPlus European 0W40 Premium Synthetic Engine Oil, 5-L
#028-7963-2
SAVE 45% ($27)
$27.99
$54.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MotoMaster OEPlus European 5W30 Premium Synthetic Engine Oil, 5-L
#028-7964-0
SAVE 45% ($27)
$27.99
$54.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
NOMA LED Shop Light Bar, 2-ft
#052-9268-6
SAVE 40%
$23.99
$39.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
PADERNO Montgomery Multi-Knife Pack Set, 3-pc
#142-9372-2
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $50)
$49.99
$99.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
CANVAS Chelsea Flush Mount, 13-in
#052-2676-6
SAVE 40% ($40)
$59.99
$99.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MotoMaster OEPLUS Domestic 5W30 Premium Synthetic Engine Oil, 5-L
#028-7960-8
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $27)
$26.99
$53.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MotoMaster OEPlus Domestic 0W20 Premium Synthetic Engine Oil, 5-L
#028-7961-6
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $27)
$26.99
$53.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MotoMaster OEPlus Domestic 5W20 Premium Synthetic Engine Oil, 5-L
#028-9971-0
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $27)
$26.99
$53.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
NOMA LED A19 100W Warm White Bulb, 8-pk
#052-9543-0
SAVE 45% ($25)
$29.99
$54.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
PADERNO Richmond Polished Finish Entertaining Flatware Set, 55-pc
#142-4892-4
SAVE 60% ($180)
$99.99
$279.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MAXIMUM 5-in Cutting & Grinding Disc Set, 25-pc
#054-1898-0
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $30)
$29.99
$59.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Peerless® Precept 1-Handle Centerset Lavatory Faucet, Chrome
#063-9944-0
SAVE 40% ($64)
$95.99
$159.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
KitchenAid Gourmet Tool Set, 17-pc
#142-5821-8
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $50)
$49.99
$99.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Joie Reusable Produce Bags, 5-pk
#142-9246-4
1/2 PRICE
$7.49
$14.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
New!
CANVAS Bubbles Tumbler Set, 12-pc
#142-9854-6
1/2 PRICE
$9.99
$19.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
MAXIMUM Thin-Wall Impact Hole Saw Set, 3-pc
#054-0313-8
SAVE 60% ($30)
$19.99
$49.99
Ships to your store for pickup
Check other stores
ADD TO CART
PADERNO Stainless Steel Everyday Pan, Dishwasher & Oven Safe, Burgandy, 28cm
#142-3934-2
SAVE 70% ($250)
$99.99
$349.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
PADERNO Fine Edge Arched Cake Pan
#142-4995-0
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $27)
$27.49
$54.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Sherwood Team Hockey Bag, Senior, 32-in
#083-9154-2
SAVE 40% ($30)
$44.99
$74.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
PADERNO Richmond Satin Flatware Set, 20-pc
#142-3403-6
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $50)
$49.99
$99.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
PADERNO Laurier Polished Flatware Set, 20-pc
#142-2871-6
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $50)
$49.99
$99.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
PADERNO Richmond Polished Flatware Set, 20-pc
#142-3402-8
SAVE 60% ($60)
$39.99
$99.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
Lagostina Kitchen Tool Set, 8-pc
#142-1832-6
1/2 PRICE (SAVE $70)
$69.99
$139.99
In-stock
ADD TO CART
```

Similarly for wallmart:

Replace the xpath value to this: `*//div[@class='css-1gwszhe e1pmil1x10']` in the same above code (with URL change), it will fetch the current page data.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get('https://www.walmart.ca/rollback?f=12+51&icid=homepage_HP_TopCategory_Rollbacks_WM&sort=Popular%3ADESC&price=20-100')
sleep(3)
driver.maximize_window()

all_products = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "*//div[@class='css-1gwszhe e1pmil1x10']")
print(all_products.text)

driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
Rollback
Similac Advance Step 2 Non-GMO Baby Formula Powder, Infant Formula, 6-24 Months, 964 grams
964 g Value Pack
(66)
$37.28
$43.97
Online price
$3.87/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
NESTLÉ® GOOD START® PLUS 1 Baby Formula, Powder 1.02 kg
1.02 KG
(352)
$41.97
$45.98
Online price
$4.11/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
Similac Pro-Advance® Step 1 Baby Formula, 0+ Months, with 2'-FL
Powder, 964 g
(21)
$43.98
$48.98
Online price
$4.56/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
Brita® Standard Water Filter, Standard Replacement Filters for Pitchers and Dispensers, BPA Free, 5 Count
With Brita® replacement water filters, you can enjoy healthier, great tasting tap water every day.
(2115)
$24.97
$29.97
Online price
Add to cart
Rollback
Enfamil A+ Gentlease, Baby Formula, Easy to Digest, Contains DHA ( a type of Omega-3 fat), Value Pack, Powder Refill, 942g
2 x 471g
(2240)
$42.97
$47.97
Online price
$4.56/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
Enfamil A+ 2, Baby Formula, Designed for 6-18 month olds, Contains DHA – an important building block of the brain, Value Pack, Powder Refill, 992g
2 x 496g
(62)
$42.97
$47.97
Online price
$4.33/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
NESTLÉ® GOOD START® PLUS 2 Baby Formula, Powder 1.02 kg
1.02 KG
(100)
$41.97
$45.98
Online price
$4.11/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
Enfamil A+, Baby Formula, Value Pack, Powder Refill, DHA (a type of Omega-3 fat) to help support brain development, Age 0-12 months, 992g
2 x 496g
(100)
$42.97
$47.97
Online price
$4.33/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
Similac Advance Step 2 Non-GMO Baby Formula, Infant Formula, Concentrated Liquid, 6-24 Months, 12x385 milliliters
12 x 385 mL
(25)
$44.64
$49.67
Online price
97¢/100ml
Add to cart
Rollback
Similac Advance Step 1 Non-GMO Baby Formula Powder, Newborn Formula, 0+ Months, 964 grams
964 g Value Pack
(43)
$37.28
$43.97
Online price
$3.87/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
Starfrit Electric Personal Blender - White
Personal Blender + 2 Cups
(494)
$25.97
$34.98
Online price
Add to cart
Rollback
NESTLÉ® GOOD START SOOTHE™ Baby Formula, Powder 942 g
942 GR
(87)
$41.97
$46.98
Online price
$4.46/100g
Add to cart
Rollback
Similac Advance Step 1 Non-GMO Baby Formula, Newborn Formula, 0+ Months, 12x385 milliliters
12 x 385 mL
(26)
$44.64
$49.67
Online price
97¢/100ml
Add to cart
Rollback
Gillette Fusion5 Power Men's Razor Blade Refills
8 Blade Refills
(3605)
$29.97
$34.97
Online price
$3.75/each
Almost sold out online!
Add to cart
Rollback
Olay Regenerist Retinol 24 Night Facial Moisturizer
50 mL
(2466)
$35.98
$38.98
Online price
Add to cart
```